# return void in a void method?

Tags: java, methods, syntax

I know I can do this:

```
void someMethod(){
 return;
 }
```

but I get a syntax error on

```
void someMethod(){
return void;
}
```

Why is the latter not allowed? It makes more sense to me.

Edit: I know what a void method is, and that I don't have to return from it at all(and probably shouldn't, in most cases) but I don't understand why I can't return void from a void method. In my opinion, there should be no keyword in the method declaration (like constructors) if the you are able to write return;.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795303/why-cant-i-return-a-void-method-call

Comment: It add extra verbosity.  So the developers probably said "let's make it shorter since we may have to write it a billion times.".........

Comment: Why return anything?  I don't add either line.  It's shorter than both.

Comment: void is a type not a value. it's like doing `return int`

Comment: @granadaCoder It's always seemed to me that the Java devs always prefer more verbosity to less.

Comment: Sounds smug and unhelpful, Kevin.

Answer (score 6):

I think both are to be shunned.  I prefer this:

```
void someMethod() {
    // do stuff; no return at bottom
}
```

I'd be willing to be that you'd find lots of methods in the JDK source code that look like this.

Comment: +1, me too. Maybe mention `return` statements in a `void` method are only useful in terms of flow control.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a method as `void`, you're saying that the method does not return a value. Attempting to return a value, therefore, is illegal. Additionally, `return void;` has a syntax error because `void` is not (indeed, cannot be) the name of an in-scope variable.

Answer (score 2):

`void` is a type, not an expression, so trying to write `return void` is the same as trying to write `return int`: syntactically invalid.

Comment: so then nothing is a value of void?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `return void;`, you are using a reserved keyword in the incorrect manner. Since it would not expect the keyword `void` in that manner, it would cause an error.

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

If you would prefer to return something, then you can `return null;` by parameterizing a type `Void` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408646/195488), but that's unconventional. Best bet is to omit `return` altogether or just say `return;`.

Answer (score 1):

`return x;` indicates that control is leaving the method and that its result is the value of `x`.

`return;` indicates that control is leaving the method without a result.

The type `void` is a type with zero values, so for `void` methods there is no `x` such that `return x` makes sense.

All non-void methods must do one of three things:

1. Fail to exit ever.
2. Finish abnormally with an exception.
3. Finish normally with zero or one return values.

Since `void` is the *only* type with zero possible values (Classes with `private` uncalled ctors don't count because of `null`), there is no possible `return` in a non-`void` method such that `return` makes sense.