# Why cannot I return void from a void function

Tags: java

Why does this code work

```
void hello()
{
hello();
return;
}
```

while this does not

```
void hello(){return hello();}
```

Error:

```
java.java:13: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
return hello();
```

(Please ignore the logical error)

The main question: Why cannot we return void to a void function?

Does Java by any means provide support another type of `void`, maybe a wrapper class called `Void`?

Comment: There is a `Void` class already.

Comment: Got it! Does void support any value apart from void?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing void with null.

Comment: _"Why does this code work"_ It doesn't really "work" as it creates an infinite recursion and finally a StackOverflowException. ;)

Comment: Lol @MarkusKauppinen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way

```
class A {
  Void a() {
    // ...
    return a();
  }
}
```

but `java.lang.Void` is an uninstantiable representation of the `void` type meaning you can't make instances out of it (and, sensibly, you aren't supposed to). Eventually, you would need to return a value, it could be a `null` - the only "legit" one I can think of.

It has applications with [generics and the Reflection API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-void-type), but I doubt it being used here for the purpose of making a recursive method fancier (?).

```
class A {
  Consumer<String> a() {
    return System.out::println;
  }
}
```

You might want to return an instance of a function that returns `void`. Then, a functional interface `java.util.function.Consumer` might be a good fit.

Actually, it could be any interface of the kind that would suit you best. For instance,

```
class A {
  Runnable a() {
    // ...
    return () -> a();
  }
}
```

Comment: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to Void;
I tried doing it in main() by returning System.out.println()

Comment: Is there any to convert `void` to `Void`?

Comment: @SonofStackoverflow no

Answer (score 1):

> he main question: Why cannot we return void to a void function?

Because `void` function does not return a value thus you cannot `return` anything. 
In void method context `return;` is just "finish method execution" or "quit method", not "return nothing";

Comment: Is there any way to return void in a void function? To support one-liner return control statements?

Comment: *To support one-liner control statments*? Than maybe you should use `boolean` as return value.

Comment: The function on which I am trying it is the main function...

Comment: And you are out of luck, `void methods` does not return values.

Answer (score 1):

As for one-liners, try this:

```
void hello() { hello(); }
```

istead of

```
void hello() { return hello(); }
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear the main function would be an conditional return and there would be other statements ahead.

Answer (score 1):

With return type `void`, you can not return anything but with return type, `Void`, you can return `null` e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello();
    }

    static Void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
```

You can find some more uses of `Void` at https://www.baeldung.com/java-void-type

Answer (score 1):

Because when a method's return value is `void` it does not accept any parameter, even `void` itself.

`return x;` indicates that control is leaving the method and that its result is the value of x.

`return;` indicates that control is leaving the method without a result.

This code does not work so I guess you should not expect yours to work too.

```
void fun () {return void;} // does not work
```

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16406603/4734439).