# How to call a method that deals with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Prompt: Write a method that reverses the sequence of elements in an array.

For example, if you call the method with the array

1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11

then the array is changed to

11 9 4 7 9 16 9 4 1

Here's what I have so far. I have no idea on how to call the method...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] array = {1,4,9,16,9,7,4,9,11};

    System.out.println(reverse(array[]));
}
public static void reverse (int[]a){
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++){
        double temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[a.length - i -1];
        temp = a[a.length - i - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here is the official tutorial on arrays.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Read the error message; it'll say exactly what is wrong. (Well, one of the things.)

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7795374/2864740

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, you also had a little mistake in reverse method, here it is :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaApplication118 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11, 5};
        reverse(array); //here you call the method
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); //print the array, using Arrays method
    }

    public static void reverse(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
            a[a.length - i - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to implement it by yourself, you could use **Apache Commons Lang** utils.

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(..)
```

does exactly what you want.

In your codeblock you assign variable `temp` twice. But the second time the value of it should be assigned to. So this is right:

```
public static void reverse (int[]a){
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++){
    double temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i -1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = temp;  //<--- here was the mistake
  }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer the OPs question(s).